# truncate text after exceeding certain size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails offers the `truncate` method when you want to truncate text that exceeds a certain character length. This is the example provided [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate):

```
truncate("Once upon a time in a world far far away")
# => "Once upon a time in a world..."
```

It truncates a given text after a given :length if text is longer than :length

But I have the following example:

```
str = "abcdefhijklmno"
```

After 12 characters I want it truncated, so the above text should look like this:

```
abcdefhijklm...
```

But I tried using the truncate method and cannot get the desired result:

```
> str = "abcdefhijklmno"
 => "abcdefhijklmno" 
> str.truncate(15)
 => "abcdefhijklmno" 
> str.truncate(14)
 => "abcdefhijklmno" 
> str.truncate(13)
 => "abcdefhijk..." 
> str.truncate(12)
 => "abcdefhij..."
```

I would think that `truncate(12)` would do it but it truncates after 9 characters. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

argument of `truncate` means size of output string (with "..."):

```
str.truncate(13)
=> "abcdefhijk..."
str.truncate(13).size
=> 13
```

You can change default omission(`...`) by empty space if you want:

```
str.truncate(13, omission: '')
=> "abcdefhijklmn"
```

More about Rails `String#truncate` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-truncate).

Comment: What I want is this: "abcdefhijklm..."  I want to keep 12 characters and add the 3 dots. That would be a total of 15 characters. Using 15 is argument still does not give desired result: str.truncate(15)
 => "abcdefhijklmno"

Comment: @Donato, it is very strange behavior, cause your string do not need to truncate, it is full. Just add `...` if you want: `str.size > 15 ? "#{str}..." : str.truncate(15)`

Comment: @Donato or you can write your own method like: `"12334554".first(3) + "..."`

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `str.truncate` will do what you want out of the box. But since it's really just an extra `if` statement, it's easy to write:

```
def trunc(str, length)
  addition = str.length > length ? '...' : ''
  "#{str.truncate(length, omission: '')}#{addition}"
end
```

Or slightly simplified, and without a Rails dependency (as mentioned by Ilya in the comments):

```
def trunc(str, len)
  "#{str.first(len)}#{'...' if str.size > len}"
end
```

And the test cases:

```
2.2.1 :005 > s = 'abcdefghijklmno'
 => "abcdefghijklmno"
2.2.1 :006 > trunc(s, 20)
 => "abcdefghijklmno"
2.2.1 :007 > trunc(s, 15)
 => "abcdefghijklmno"
2.2.1 :008 > trunc(s, 14)
 => "abcdefghijklmn..."
2.2.1 :009 > trunc(s, 13)
 => "abcdefghijklm..."
2.2.1 :010 > trunc(s, 0)
 => "..."
2.2.1 :011 > trunc(s, 1)
 => "a..."
```

Comment: May be simplified: `"#{str.first(len)}#{'...' if str.size > len }"`

Comment: By the way, this answer is almost full copy of my comments)

Comment: And you've added `Or slightly simplified` section only after my last comment too)

Comment: Sure 'nuff. If you want to move your comments into your answer where they're more discoverable, I'm happy to delete my answer, since you beat me to the punch. If not, I'll leave it as is - I think answers are superior to comment threads in terms of discoverability.

Comment: No need to delete, you can just add `as mentioned in comments` in future, it is a really good tone. Sorry for my rudeness, i did not want to offend you.

Comment: Works for me. Cheers!